# ARIMA (p and q values)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am trying to do Arima forecasting, i differenced once so d=1, Im not sure what my p and q values need to be, please check screenshots of acf and pacf below:

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do Box-Jenkins, instead of a more modern approach using information criteria as per `auto.arima()` in the `forecast` package for R?

Comment: @StephanKolassa It is for my research I am advised to practise arima modelling :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ACF is (more or less) exponentially decaying.

Your PACF has a clear peak at a lag of 1, and much less clear ones at lags 2 and 34.

I recommend [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/). Based on [the section on ACF/PACF reading (scroll down)](https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html), it looks like your data may be best described by an ARIMA(1,1,0) process.

For "real" forecasting, an automated model selection based on information criteria, as implemented in `auto.arima()` in the `forecast` package for R, is usually better (and more scalable).

---

EDIT: [Richard Hardy makes the excellent point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517585/arima-p-and-q-values/517589?noredirect=1#comment953634_517589) that one should be very careful about higher integration orders than 1. An order of 2 is similar to a quadratic trend. This is very rarely reasonable, except for very short horizons. As an illustration, here are twenty randomly simulated ARIMA(1,2,0) paths, where the AR parameter is sampled from $U[-0.5,0.5]$ and the innovations are the default $N(0,1)$ - note how often and how soon the paths go outside $\pm 100$, even after fewer than $100$ steps:

[image: ARIMA(1,2,0)]

R code:

```
opar <- par(mai=c(.5,.5,.1,.1),mfrow=c(4,5),las=1)
    for ( ii in 1:20 ) {
        set.seed(ii)
        plot(arima.sim(model=list(ar=runif(1,-.5,.5),order=c(1,2,0)),n=100),
            xlab="",ylab="")
    }
par(opar)
```

Comment: +1 and congrats on 80k :)

Comment: Hm. Reducing the standard deviation is not how the order of differencing is usually decided. Usually one would run unit root tests. I recommend [Hyndman & Khandakar (2008)](https://www.jstatsoft.org/htaccess.php?volume=27&type=i&issue=03&paper=true), who describe how the order of differencing is decided in `auto.arima()`.

Comment: @RichardHardy: thank you :)

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes I did that too, and the 2nd differencing definitely seems better. Now I cannot figure out what P and Q will be, I assumed it will 1 and 1? So ARIMA(1,2,1)?

Comment: Based on the FPP2 section, it would be ARIMA(1,2,0). You can't use ACF/PACF if *both* the AR and the MA order are larger than zero. You might also try running your series through `auto.arima()` and see what that would give.

Comment: @jason, be careful with differencing of order more than 1. There are not so many real-life examples of processes that can be argued to be integrated of order 2 or higher. Differencing is often misused when deterministic trends or seasonality is present (resulting in *overdifferencing*); perhaps you need to consider adjusting for such things in other ways.

Comment: @RichardHardy Hi bro, the data I am using is seasonally adjusted data. Also to check the second differencing I did Arima variable (0,2,0) and I did Arima variable (0,1,0) - the standard deviation is lower for the 2nd differencing, and the AIC/BIC values are also lower for the 2nd differencing. That is how I concluded the 2nd differencing is better. Am i correct?

Comment: Per above, the standard deviation doesn't tell you anything. And you can't compare AIC/BIC values between series with different orders of differencing (I'm sure I explained that somewhere here on CV, but can't find it right now). Use a unit root test or similar, and as @RichardHardy wrote, be hesitant about higher orders.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure of the command for unit root testing (is this dicker fuller?) I will have a look on google for this/manual. Thanks @StephanKolassa

Comment: I spent years studying the classical approaches - and then found out that with mixed p and q they commonly did not work :) Which was annoying. It's also questionable how well they work with real world data. Also it is generally agreed that the unit root test do not work great especially with a near unit root situation. The recommendation I decided to go with is use test that have a null of stationarity and non-stationarity and see if they agree. :)

Comment: @user54285: well, the real world applicability of ARIMA is another big question mark all by itself. Recall the incredulous reaction of expert statisticians when it was suggested that other methods might forecast better ([Hyndman, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.03.015)). My suspicion is that ARIMA keeps being taught because you can prove actual mathematical theorems about it, not because it performs well in forecasting.

Comment: @StephanKolassa that is fascinating to know. I always thought forecasting was an unusual element of statistics anyhow because it combines statistics with other things (in the old days ARIMA was as much an art as a science). And because practitioners (like me) actually use it a lot. The advice that I have seen and use at my work is to combine many models into one average result, even methods like exponential smoothing and ARIMA that make very different assumptions. Also there is something to be said with real world data to make fewer assumptions than ARIMA does. Irishstats stressed that.